# How to calculate the Gaussian Integral in specific region?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Firstly, I know that the Gaussian Integral formula, e.g.,
$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$. But, I am now being encountered a problem when the integral region is not $[-\infty,+\infty]$. Specifically, I would like to calculate the integral as $\int^b_ce^{-ax^2}dx$. Is there any possible solution?

Besides, I would like to further calculate integral as $\int^b_cxe^{-ax^2}dx$ and $\int^b_cx^2e^{-ax^2}dx$. Is there any trick that I can follow? If you can show some specific deduction or give some references for me, I will highly appreciate your help and time. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some results : the first come from the definition of the $erf$ function, the other are obtained by integration by parts.

$$\int e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a} x\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}$$ $$\int x e^{-ax^2}dx=-\frac{e^{-a x^2}}{2 a}$$ $$\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a} x\right)}{4 a^{3/2}}-\frac{x e^{-a x^2}}{2
   a}$$ $$\int x^3 e^{-ax^2}dx=-\frac{e^{-a x^2} \left(a x^2+1\right)}{2 a^2}$$ $$\int x^4 e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a} x\right)}{8 a^{5/2}}-\frac{x e^{-a x^2}
   \left(2 a x^2+3\right)}{4 a^2}$$ There is a generalization using the gamma function $$\int x^k e^{-ax^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2} x^{k+1} \left(a x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2} (-k-1)} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{k+1}{2},a x^2\right)$$

**Edit** *(8 years later)*

Let $ax^2=t$ to make

$$\int x^k e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} a^{-\frac{k+1}{2}}\int  t^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\,e^{-t}\,dt=-\frac{1}{2} a^{-\frac{k+1}{2}}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2},t\right)$$

Comment: It's a fine answer (though I haven't checked the formulas), but calling it a **Hint** seems a bit misleading. OP may find these links to the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) useful.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen. You are perfectly correct. I am just in a hurry ! I remove the "hint". Cheers.

Comment: Yep, familiar with hurry, been there, done that, got the T-shirt.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and time. The lower limits of the formulas are all 0?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen. Thanks for your time and help. But could you please show the details of the third formula? That is the $\int^a_0 x^2e^{-ax^2}dx$. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Many thanks. Could please show the details of the third formula? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The third formula would be the one with $\int x^2e^{-ax^2}\,dx$. Write the integrand as $x\cdot xe^{-ax^2}$ and do a partial integration, integrating $xe^{-ax^2}$ and differentiating $x$. The same procedure should generalize to the later integrals.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen. Noted with many thanks.